# Get files from diff between branches

Tags: git

I have two branches - `dev` and `feature`.

The branch `feature` is very large - it has 10+ commits and 100+ new files, without changing old files.

With git, can I save the difference between branches to files?
The result should be in the form of just files with their structure preserved for further work with them.

Comment: "just files with their structure preserved" -> can you elaborate? You can have a list of new/changed files, but is it what you want?

Comment: @RomainValeri thx for answer. I want fix mistake - some project integrate into another project, but i want divide to two independent projects. And first step - get all files with project structure (folders, files)

Answer (score 0):

`git format-patch <commit range>` will produce a text output of all commits, which can be applied somewhere else (using `git am`) :

```
# default behavior is to create 1 patch file per commit :
git format-patch dev..feature

# or use '--stdout' to get all the output in one go :
git format-patch --stdout dev..feature
```

This method will also preserve the authors and messages of existing commits.

[This blog post](https://devconnected.com/how-to-create-and-apply-git-patch-files/) gives a pretty good introduction on how to use these commands together.

---

Another (simpler) way is to produce one single patch using `git diff` :

```
git diff dev...feature > feature.patch   # 3 dots notation with 'git diff' means :
                                         # 'diff on feature since its fork point from dev'
```

and apply it using `git apply` :

```
git apply feature.patch
```